# Arduino and RC Transmitter

Tags: arduino

I am new to Arduino and to this forum and this is my first Arduino project besides the tutorials.

I am trying to control a servo using a rc transmitter/receiver and the Arudino. The reason why I am using a Arduino instead of connecting the servo directly to the RC receiver is that the RC can only generate a PWM of 1000µs to 2000µs while I need a PWM of 600µs to 2400µs to get the full range of motion of my servo. What I have tried to do is to read the value from pulseIn(), then mapping this value to 0 to 180 degree as written in code below (which utilizes servo library).

However, with this code, the motor behaviour is weird. As I move the radio transmitter control stick through its range of motion, the motor rotates from 0 to 45 degrees, back from 45 to 0, 0 to 45, and back to 0 again instead of sweeping from 0 to 180 degrees. Could anyone please offer some help or advice?

Thank you very much

```cpp
#include <Servo.h> 
Servo myservo;

int ch1; 
int ch2;
int ch3;
int degree;

void setup() {
  pinMode(7, INPUT);
  myservo.attach(9);
  Serial.begin(9600); 
}

void loop() {
  ch3 = pulseIn(7, HIGH, 25000);
  degree = ((ch3-1250)* 180)/700;
  Serial.print("Channel 3:");
  Serial.println(ch3);
  myservo.write(degree);
  delay(5);  // waits 5ms for the servo to reach the position 
}
```

Comment: Servos are controlled with a pulse _width_ modulated signal.  The units on width are time, not frequency.  In the question above the values for the input are 1000 - 2000 microseconds.  The desired output is 600 - 2400 microseconds to get the full angular rotation.  The edit to add 'Hz' to the question was incorrect.

Answer (score 3):

You are overflowing the **int** data type.  The signed value can only be -32768 to +32767.  See [int docs](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/Int)

Your formula is all **int**'s and the compiler will not guess that you might need a larger intermediate value.  The multiply by 180 is a red flag.  (2000-1250)*180 = 135000 = boom

To understand the math, break down a formula into the individual operations as shown in the test program below.  That is essentially what the compiler is doing for you.

Run the program below and you will see the failure.  Just after the out value reaches 45, the intermediate value overflows and the formula breaks down.

```
in: 1040 out: 39   t0: -210 t1: 27736 t2: 39  
in: 1048 out: 41   t0: -202 t1: 29176 t2: 41  
in: 1056 out: 43   t0: -194 t1: 30616 t2: 43  
in: 1064 out: 45   t0: -186 t1: 32056 t2: 45  
in: 1072 out: -45   t0: -178 t1: -32040 t2: -45  
in: 1080 out: -43   t0: -170 t1: -30600 t2: -43
```

Use this program below as a test fixture.  Modify the data types to use unsigned int and you will be able to make the output behave as you need.

```
int ch3;
int degree;

void setup() {
    ch3 = 1000;
    Serial.begin(9600); 
}

void loop() {
    int t0, t1, t2;

    degree = ((ch3-1250)* 180)/700;

    t0 = ch3 - 1250;
    t1 = t0 * 180;
    t2 = t1 / 700;

    Serial.print("in: ");
    Serial.print(ch3);
    Serial.print(" out: ");
    Serial.print(degree);
    Serial.print("   t0: ");
    Serial.print(t0);
    Serial.print(" t1: ");
    Serial.print(t1);
    Serial.print(" t2: ");
    Serial.println(t2);

    ch3 += 8;
    if(ch3 > 2400) {
        ch3 = 1000;
    }

    delay(100);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As a note, you may have more Arduino/servo luck on https://robotics.stackexchange.com/.

What are you seeing on the serial output? Is ch3 cycling from 0 to 45 or from 0 to 180? Don't forget that `map()` is designed to do what you're doing by hand here.

My first suspicion is that you're occasionally getting 0 back from `pulseIn` either because you're timing out, or you're starting your reading in the middle of a pulse (which could lead to a shorter pulse than you expect).